# Jquery Ajax POST request failing

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

could someone tell me why this request doesn't execute the success code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var post_data = [];
        $('.trade_window').load('signals.php?action=init'); 
        setInterval(function(){
            post_data = [   {market_number:1, name:$('.trade_window .market_name_1').text().trim()},
                    {market_number:2, name:$('.trade_window .market_name_2').text().trim()}];

                    console.log(JSON.stringify({markets: post_data}));

            $.ajax({
                        url: 'signals.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                       data:{markets:post_data},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(){
                            console.log("IT WORKED");
                        },
                        failure: function(result){
                            console.log("FAILED");
                            console.log(result);
                        }
            });
        }, 10000); 
    });
```

When i check the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify({markets: post_data}));` is get this as a result in google chrome:

> {"markets":[{"market_number":1,"name":"GBPUSD"},{"market_number":2,"name":"EURUSD"}]}

But i never get "IT WORKED" printed to the console which means it never works.

on futher checking i made an if statement in my php which checked if anything was posted

```
if(!empty($_POST))
        echo "POSTED!!!!!";
    else
        echo "NOT POSTED";
```

But i always get "NOT POSTED" printed on the screen.

any ideas?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is signals.php expecting json? Did you try sending it to PHP as: `data:{markets:post_data},` You could also add `failure: function(){}` to the Ajax.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni Yes, i had this working with GET instead of post before this. Also I'm getting a return from the PHP file so we know it's the right URL.

Comment: @DevalShah Hey, i just trying the print_r and just got an empty array.

Comment: You're expecting a JSON result returned, so anything else will fail. Try adding on a fail() function to see what the problem is.

Comment: @Skelly I just tried `data: {markets:post_data}, still nothing will add the failure method now.

Comment: try setting pos_data with `{}` instead of `[]`, Not sure but worth a shot.

Comment: `contentType: "application/json",` put this in `ajax` call

Comment: If your endpoint answers after `GET` it doesn't mean it will also answer with a `POST`, make a test `POST` from an external tool to be sure...

Comment: Acutally, it should be `data: {markets: post_data},`, you want an object, not a string, at least you do if you're trying to access this with `$_POST['markets']`, so drop the stringify function !

Comment: Thanks for the help so far people, this is the updated code, Added a failure function and it doesn't even execute that method...?

Comment: @eric.itzhak Thaanks for that but sadly it didn't work just an error.

Comment: There is no failure() function, it's error(), or you chain on a fail() function at the end.

Comment: @ragebunny try adding `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

Comment: tried the contentType. I've got a feeling there is something really stupid that I'm not seeing!

Comment: Try the code in this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RJYTm/2/) and see what the console says ?

Comment: @adeneo Hi, i get this error when trying your code `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done'`

Comment: In what version of jQuery ?

Comment: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` 1.8.3 You should i should use a newer version? @adeneo

Comment: Nope, 1.8.3 supports done() and fail() just fine, and the posted fiddle returns the errors just fine to the console, so you should'nt be getting those errors in that version of jQuery. You're sure you don't have two jQuery versions included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var post_data = [];
    $('.trade_window').load('signals.php?action=init'); 
    setInterval(function(){
        post_data = [   {market_number:1, name:$('.trade_window .market_name_1').text().trim()},
                {market_number:2, name:$('.trade_window .market_name_2').text().trim()}];

                console.log(JSON.stringify({markets: post_data}));

        $.ajax({
                    url: 'signals.php/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                   data:{markets:post_data},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(){
                        console.log("IT WORKED");
                    },
                    failure: function(result){
                        console.log("FAILED");
                        console.log(result);
                    }
        });
    }, 10000); 
});
```

Comment: Right, This code works. Buuuuuut the only thing i can find that hasn't already been posted here or tried is the '/' at the end of signals.php. Why would this change anything?

Comment: ;) it's all about http request you made! you have to put '/' after any url you want to post some data to it!

Comment: Hey, One more thing, this works fine now but i can't seem to be able to grab the response from the php script any ideas?

Comment: you have to return data to success function. something like this: 

success: function(data) {
    $("#someID").html(data);
  }

@ragebunny

Answer (score 1):

You can easily pass `POST` data in `ajax` request without `JSON.stringify`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var post_data = [];
        $('.trade_window').load('signals.php?action=init'); 
        setInterval(function(){
            post_data = '&market_number1=1&name1='+$(".trade_window .market_name_1").text().trim()+'&market_number2=2&name2='+$(".trade_window .market_name_2").text().trim();

            $.ajax({


                        url: 'signals.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: post_data,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(){
                            console.log("IT WORKED");
                        }
            });
        }, 2000); 
    });
```

Comment: Yes you can, but that's not the way to do it !

Comment: ya but i suggesting alternative solution..:)

Comment: this is simple way to get `POST` data in `PHP` script

Comment: Yeah, it's strange because it's loading the php script but for some reason the post data isn't getting through to it. It's really starting to annoy me now.

Comment: @ragebunny I think you should send `ajax` request to different php file then `signals.php`, made new file `signals1.php` and put php code there

Comment: Well i have it working now and it works because i have put `url: 'signals.php/',` instead of `url: 'signals.php',` Don't ask me why because i don't really know....

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use json.stringyfy and read the data on php side.. this is the right way to do it

> data: {json: JSON.stringify({markets: post_data})}

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var post_data = [];
    //$('.trade_window').load('signals.php?action=init'); 
    setInterval(function(){
        post_data = [   {market_number:1, name:$('.trade_window .market_name_1').text().trim()},
                {market_number:2, name:$('.trade_window .market_name_2').text().trim()},];

                console.log(JSON.stringify({markets: post_data}));

        $.ajax({


                    url: 'signals.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {json: JSON.stringify({markets: post_data})},
                    dataType: "json",
                    done: function($msg){
                        console.log("IT WORKED");
                    }
        });
    }, 2000); 
});
```

now in your PHP you can do whatever

```
$json = json_decode($_POST["json"]);
print_r($json);
```

or

```
    if(isset($_POST["json"])){
$json = json_decode($_POST["json"]);
if(!empty($json))
        echo "POSTED!!!!!";
    else
        echo "NOT POSTED";
}
```

DIns

Comment: I tried this edit and i tried using the second php code, i get an error in php `NOTICE: UNDEFINED INDEX: JSON IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\site\MEMBERS\SIGNALS\SIGNALS.PHP ON LINE 8`

Comment: are you getting this error on console?... you should not access signals.php  directly..

Comment: No, this file is being loaded through the JS and the php file is generating HTML to output to the screen and thats how it's coming out.

Comment: No errors now but still nothing is posted to the php file. This is a bit strange.

Comment: Could it be something to do with the amount of time it takes to send the data and execute the file? even if it was i didn't think it would take more than 10 seconds (which is the interval i've set)

Comment: what do you mean by posted to PHP file?.. its an ajax request.. you will be able to only see the response in your console.. if you want to post something in your current page .. you will have to add to ur html using jquery..

Comment: Sorry I think i'm confusing things, by posted to the file i mean that using POST to send data to signals.php for it to use when executing it's code..... That is right? isn't it?

Comment: well its tested and is working fine for me.. see the firebug cosole to test if you get POSTED message.. and if you get than its working...

Comment: Using firebug i do get the response "POSTED!!!"..... Check the success method isn't executed,but i don't know why?